# How to create an incremental view where old data is not updated?

Tags: oracle, plsql, view

Is it possible to create a materialized view where it is only incremental?

I would like the old data already inserted not to be updated, only new insertions should be included in the view.

If possible, how could I do it?

Is there any documentation or any place I can use as a guide?

Comment: You would have to write the MV query in such a way that it only selected the new rows from the table. You might leverage the content of the materialized view log with primary key to do that.

Comment: Do you want to see _every_ row as it existed at the point of insert, or *only* _new_ rows added since the last refresh?

Comment: Which version of ORACLE ?

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer more reputable than Chris' answer.  I recognized his name immediately when I saw his comment and his answer is very detailed.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to see **every** row at the time of insert in an MV the short answer is:

You can't.

A `materialized view` stores the result of a query as it exists *now*, not some time in the past. So after updating a row you can either see its current values or exclude it from the MV.

If you want to preserve/view the state of data at insert you have a few options:

- Make the table insert-only (possibly storing change history within the table)
- Capture the data when its added (e.g. via triggers) into another table
- Use [Flashback Data Archive](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/flashback-data-archive-fda-enhancements-12cr1) to store change history and view it with [Flashback Query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/flashback.html#GUID-0BD1F4BD-894B-47BA-A44B-74BCA4CFD60E)

Which of these is most appropriate depends on why you need view the data at insert.

---

Technically it is possible to view data at the time of insert - up to a point.

With Flashback Version Query you can see changes to the table over time. So you can do something like this:

```
create table t (
  c1 int, c2 int,
  insert_date timestamp,
  update_date timestamp
);

exec dbms_session.sleep(10);

insert into t values ( 1, 1, systimestamp, systimestamp );
insert into t values ( 2, 2, systimestamp, systimestamp );

commit;

create materialized view mv 
as 
  select t.*
  from t 
    versions between scn minvalue 
    and maxvalue
where versions_operation = 'I';

exec dbms_session.sleep(10);

update t
set    c2 = 9999, 
       update_date = systimestamp
where  c1 = 2;

insert into t values ( 3, 3, systimestamp, systimestamp );

commit;

exec dbms_mview.refresh ( 'mv' );

select * from t;

C1      C2 INSERT_DATE                       UPDATE_DATE                      
 1       1 26-JUL-2021 13.49.51.666954000    26-JUL-2021 13.49.51.666954000    
 2    9999 26-JUL-2021 13.49.51.712259000    26-JUL-2021 13.50.08.421872000    
 3       3 26-JUL-2021 13.50.08.462300000    26-JUL-2021 13.50.08.462300000  

select *
from   mv;

C1    C2 INSERT_DATE                       UPDATE_DATE                      
 3     3 26-JUL-2021 13.50.08.462300000    26-JUL-2021 13.50.08.462300000    
 2     2 26-JUL-2021 13.49.51.712259000    26-JUL-2021 13.49.51.712259000    
 1     1 26-JUL-2021 13.49.51.666954000    26-JUL-2021 13.49.51.666954000
```

This uses undo to reconstruct history. Eventually older changes will drop off and you're back to only seeing the current state. By default you only get **15 minutes** worth of changes!

If you want to store history for long period of time, Flashback Data Archive is the way to go.